# How to wish a good feeling for a person who had a flu?

Tags: expressions

A person has messaged me after a week and he had a flue. How should I respond to the message? Do we have a common sentence for that?

Comment: 'I hope you are feeling (or 'will soon feel') better'. It's 'the flu', by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no formula (like saying "bless you" when someone sneezes).  You can just say something general like "I hope you're feeling better". And you could sign off your message with "Take care of yourself". However, any expression of sympathy is acceptable. There are no rules on what you have to say.

When someone is sick you can say "Get better soon".

Answer (score -1):

May God bless you with health Amen